# Bringing a laptop to Japan - do I need to pay import taxes?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, japan, electronic-items

Can I bring my laptop (which costs probably more than 200000JPY) to Japan without paying taxes? Seems like they require to pay taxes for everything which cost more than 10000JPY if total value exceeds 200000JPY, so if i will bring my laptop, i will probably need to pay taxes and for my phone and camera too?

[customs rules](http://www.customs.go.jp/kaisei/youshiki/form_C/C5360-Br.pdf)

Comment: Are you leaving the laptop in Japan when you leave?

Comment: Generally, visitors are never required to pay taxes for electronics intended for personal use that will leave the country with them. If a country do tax them, this will annoy basically all visitors.

Answer (score 7):

If you're a **Japanese resident**, you will have to pay tax as you're importing a device over the limit.

If you're **not a Japanese resident**, you don't have to pay anything since you're only importing the item temporarily. Hundreds of thousands of people carry expensive laptops with them when traveling to Japan, without any issues. The [Japanese customs website](http://www.customs.go.jp/english/summary/passenger.htm) confirms this:

> - Personal Effects and Professional Equipment Clothes, toiletries, and other personal effects for your personal use, as well as portable
>     professional equipment that will be used during your stay in Japan,
>     are all free of duty and/or tax, if they are considered quantitatively
>     appropriate and are not for sale.

Comment: A reference would be nice.

Comment: Here's a reference. [Procedures of Passenger Clearance](http://www.customs.go.jp/english/summary/passenger.htm) :"Clothes, toiletries, and other personal effects for your personal use, as well as portable professional equipment that will be used during your stay in Japan, are all free of duty and/or tax, if they are considered quantitatively appropriate and are not for sale.".

Comment: @JonathanReez On a note about enforcement, as a resident and system engineer, I regularly bring <2 laptops + <2 tablet PCs (total price exceeds 5 hundred thousand yen for those 4 devices alone) at a time to and from Japan without having ever been told to pay duties on them.

Answer (score 2):

Bringing laptops, cameras or phones without box is totally safe and tax free if they are not covered with diamonds and gold. No one will check how much is real price if amount is reasonable and does not look like it's for sale.

I brought stuff to Japan for more than 1M yen several times without hiding anything, no problem at all. I had pair of laptops for 300K yen each, pair of phones 100K each, camera for 200K and set of lenses for total 300K. Security staff saw all that and did not ask even a question. I did not try to bring stuff in boxes though.

I'm Japanese resident but some of my colleagues were not, though they brought similar stuff. No difference.